# amchart accessing values inside a structured data object, part 2

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I had a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296962/amchart-accessing-values-inside-a-structured-data-object) controlling amcharts data object. Thank you @kikon for your help! 
This time I cant seem to tweak the ouput of `tooltip` from the json object, let me explain:

From this function:

```
var series = chart.series.push(
      am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
          name: name,
          xAxis: xAxis,
          yAxis: yAxis,
          valueYField: field,
          categoryYField: field+'_text',
          categoryXField: "year",
          tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
              pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
          })
      })
  );
```

`categoryYField` is created from:

```
const dataProcessed = data.map(o=>Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).flatMap(
      ([k, v])=>[
          [k, v ?.[0]?.[positioningKey] ?? v],
          [k+"_text", Object.entries( v?.[0] ?? {[defaultKey]: v} )
              .map( 
                  ([k, v]) => (k.length > 0 ? '\n' + k + ': ' : '') + v
              ).join("")
          ]
      ]
    )
  ));
```

But I would like to populate the tooltip only from the string portion of the data object `bb`: `var data = [{year:"1930", italy:[{aa:20,bb:"21"}], germany:[{aa:30,bb:"44"}], uk:[{aa:40,bb:"77"}] }, {year: "1934", italy: 1,germany: 2,uk: 6}, {year: "1938",italy: 2,germany: 3,uk: 1}];`

Currently it takes values from `aa` and joins it together with `bb`. 
`aa` is necessary for `valueYField` from `chart.series` above so the data object needs this value but how can I control tooltip to display only `bb`?

```
let tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      labelText: '[bold]{name}[/]{categoryY}'
  });
```

Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjzL1oq3/1)   
thank you
anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to control the contents of the tooltip from the function

```js
([k, v]) => (k.length > 0 ? '\n' + k + ': ' : '') + v
```

It is mapped over the entries of each data point.

If you want to exclude the `positioningKey`, you can do it this way:

```js
([k, v]) => k !== positioningKey ? 
            (k.length > 0 ? '\n' + k + ': ' : '') + v : ''
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lh2n4jk/)

If you wanted to also exclude the keys themselves from the output (keep just the values):

```js
([k, v], idx, a) => k !== positioningKey ?
             v + (idx < a.length - 1 ? ', ' : '')  : ''
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lh2n4jk/1/)